# Как задать в андроид статический IP в WiFi сети из кода

Tags: java, android, ip, wifi, static

Как задать статический ip WiFi сети из кода в андроиде. Как задать все параметры Wifi и подключиться к сети?

Comment: Что значит "статический ip WiFi сети"? Подключение к wifi происходит по ssid.

Comment: В настройках подключения к сети в дефолтных настройках можно выбрать статический айпи, как это сделать но из кода со своего приложения, не запуская дефолтные настройки?

Comment: универсального решения нет, до 4 андроида ещё можно было реализовать, а выше уже нет. Костыли только через рут могут помочь.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как просто подсоедениться к сети с приложения? Использую WifiConfiguration и устанавливаю конфигу SSID и presharedKey. Потом просто manager.addNetwork(config)  и оно не работает, что не так?

Comment: нужен код. По такому описанию ничего не ясно.

Comment: на котлине var wfManager:WifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        wfManager.setWifiEnabled(true)
        var config:WifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
        config.SSID = "\""+nameWIFI+"\""
        config.preSharedKey = "\""+password.text.toString()+"\""
        wfManager.addNetwork(config)

Comment: не вижу факта подключения к сети в коже, только добавление в менеджер. Почитайте документацию нормально.

Comment: спасибо большое